# @State bugs my TextField located at navbar - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navbar, textfield

I have a custom TextField that is located on my navbar, i don't know why this is happening but when i click on any letter, my keyboard is hidden.

[image]

```
@State var value = ""

// Body view calls
.navigationBarItems(trailing: SearchBar())

func SearchBar() -> some View {
    if (isSearchMode) {
        return (
            AnyView(
                CustomTextField(
                    text: $value,
                    isFirstResponder: true,
                    placeholder: "Testing",
                    keyboardType: UIKeyboardType.webSearch
                )
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                .padding()
            )
        )
    }
   return AnyView(
        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .gesture(
                TapGesture()
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        self.isSearchMode = true
                    }
            )
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it is hard to give you a for sure answer without more of your code but it is most likely the use of `AnyView`. When you use `AnyView` and some `@State` changes causing it to redraw it loses any other statefulness such as being edited.

You can likely fix this by changing your `SearchBar()` to this:

```swift
func SearchBar() -> some View {
    Group {
        if (isSearchMode) {
            CustomTextField(
                text: $value,
                isFirstResponder: true,
                placeholder: "Testing",
                keyboardType: UIKeyboardType.webSearch
            )
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
            .padding()
        } else {
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .gesture(
                    TapGesture()
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            self.isSearchMode = true
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}
```